# value is not calculating in function that i am getting from jquery

Tags: performance, jquery-ui, jquery

i have this function whom i need to get different values from dropdown. all values are coming right but only one drop down is not calculating is that is donation values in the function. it is coming in each condition as well but it is not calculating. please help buddies..
my jquery function is: all values are coming from dropdowns. i am not sure why donation value is not calculating. much depressed now.

my HTML is:

```
<select name="rCountry" id="recipCountry" onchange="getvals()">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
  <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option><option value="AX">Aland</option>
  <option value="AL">Albania</option>
  <!-- ... other countries omitted ... -->
  <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
  <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>

<select name="Country" id="country" required="">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
  <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option><option value="AX">Aland</option>
  <option value="AL">Albania</option>
  <!-- ... other countries omitted ... -->
  <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>

<select name="subscription" id="subscription" class="width_379" onchange="getvals()">
  <option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="1">1 year (four issues) for <?php echo "$19.95"; ?></option>
  <option value="2">2 year (eight issues) for <?php echo "$".(2*19.95); ?></option>
  <option value="3">3 year (twelve issues) for <?php echo "$".(3*19.95); ?></option>
  <option value="4">4 year (sixteen issues) for <?php echo "$".(4*19.95); ?></option>
  <option value="5">5 year (twenty issues) for <?php echo "$".(5*19.95); ?></option>
</select>

<select name="donation" id="donation" class="width_379" onchange="getvals()">
  <option selected="selected" value="">---</option>
  <option value="100">$100</option>
  <option value="200">$200</option>
  <option value="300">$300</option>
  <option value="400">$400</option>
  <option value="500">$500</option>
</select>
```

And my javascript:

```
function getvals(){
  var coun;
  var donVal;
  var total;
  var subs  = $('#subscription').val();
  var dona  = $('#donation').val();
  var Rcoun = $('#country').val();
  var Bcoun = $('#recipCountry').val();

  if(Rcoun=='US' || Bcoun=='US'){
    coun = 0;
  else{
    coun = 17;
  }
  if(dona==''){
    donVal = 0;
  }else{
    donVal = dona;
  }

  if(subs=='1'){
    total = 19.95+coun+donVal;
  } if(subs=='2'){
    total = 39.9+coun+donVal;
  } if(subs=='3'){
    total = 59.85+coun+donVal;
  } if(subs=='4'){
    total = 79.8+coun+donVal;
  } if(subs=='5'){
    total = 99.75+coun+donVal;
  }
  var totalVal = total;
  //alert(totalVal);
}
```

Comment: please anyone???? i am badly stuck at this point from almost 3 hours.

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: i have provide the html please. these are two dropdowns whose values should be calculated together.

Comment: NO ONE FROM WHOLE FORUM??? ANY JQUERY EXPERT PLEASE??????

Comment: Post the relevant html for `#country` and `#receiptCountry`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy i have posted all now.....

Comment: @MuHaMmAdMoHsIn, see http://jsfiddle.net/dmUke/, if this solves your problem ping me

Comment: @Satpal you are extreme life saver buddy.. thank you please. your answer has solved this. how did you do this???:)

Comment: @Satpal i want to rate you answer how can i do this??:) its very nice to get your help here.

Comment: @Satpal why you use +dona??? can you please help me giving this concept?? thanks

Comment: @Satpal please Buddy????? can you explain to me??

Comment: @MuHaMmAdMoHsIn, `donVal = +dona;` basically it converts dona to number. Suggestion You should accept only answer if that solved your problem

Comment: ok ok thank you please your this concept really helps me alot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('#donation option:selected').val()
```

instead of

```
$('#donation').val()
```

Since you are using jQuery u can use class selector for performing same operation instead of calling the `getvals()` on change event. Say calc is the class name for the selects, then you could write

```
$('.calc').change(function(e){
   .........
  .........
 });
```

You can find the complete code in fiddle..

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qS49R/1/)

Comment: value is coming right but its not calculating in sum...... that is my actual problem...

Comment: i am saying everything is fine dear but donation value is not calculating in overall result. please?

Comment: @Noupal.M its great and perfect..... you have save my much time today.. thanks buddy....